# bash multiple if statement inside loop is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to bash scripting, I have a file and i want to check each line but it is not working.

**My bach script code**

```
declare -a arr

for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ ))
do
    if [[ ${arr[$i]} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
      echo ${arr[$i]}" numbr"
    
    else
        echo "No match"
     fi
done
```

Why only last line is match ? is there any space or line break issue ? suggest me some solution

Comment: Though it can be refactored but your script is running fine

Comment: Print array values using `declare -p arr`

Comment: Sounds like carriage returns

Comment: @anubhava after -a to -p and i print their values
123
Rashid
235
454555

Comment: @MuhammadRashid, do `od -c file.txt` and look for `\r` characters

Comment: @glennjackman
0000000   1   2   3  \r  \n   R   a   s   h   i   d  \r  \n   2   3   5
0000020  \r  \n   4   5   4   5   5   5
0000030

Comment: @glennjackman how to remove \r on my above code ?

Comment: `dos2unix` or `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is saved in "DOS" format, with \r\n line endings.

To convert to "unix" format:

```sh
dos2unix file.txt
# or, if that's not installed
sed -i 's/\r$//' file.txt
```

---

tangentially, I find the POSIX character class can describe what you want to match:

```sh
[[ ${arr[$i]} =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo "${arr[i]} numbr"
[[ ${arr[$i]} =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+$ ]] && echo "${arr[i]} ltr only"
[[ ${arr[$i]} =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]] && echo "${arr[i]} both"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is MS-DOS line endings of `$'\r\n'` instead of `$'\n'` only.

You can remove the offending `$'\n'` on-the-fly like this:

```sh
mapfile -t arr < <(tr -d '\r' <file.txt)
```

Other than that, I suggest you check you script with https://shellcheck.net/ as it has some issues